# LazyBoolean on pyspark when inserting on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, maven, apache-spark, pyspark

I really need help.

This is a repeated question ( [py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.save. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60120705/py4j-protocol-py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o59-save-java-la) ) as it has no answer.

I'm trying to insert a Dataframe on MongoDB version v3.6.17 or v4.2.3 but fail both times. I had tried my own data and the official documentation example ( https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python/write-to-mongodb/ ), but it returns

> ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/LazyBoolean

[image]

I had other issues trying to do this simple task, for example ( [Can't connect to Mongo DB via Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45142629/cant-connect-to-mongo-db-via-spark), [Spark and MongoDB application in Scala 2.10 maven built error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40357646/spark-and-mongodb-application-in-scala-2-10-maven-built-error) ) and read some possible solutions like ( https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/examples/src/test/python/introduction.py ) but with no success.

My Spark version is 2.4.4, Python 3.7.6, I'm using IntelliJ 2019.3 as IDE.

[image]
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row    
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from select import select
#import org.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource  #  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
#import org.mongodb.spark                    #  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
#import org.bson.Document                    #  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'org'
from linecache import cache
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, monotonically_increasing_id


if __name__ == "__main__":

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("spark_python") \
    .master("local") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
print("http://desktop-f5ffrvd:4040/jobs/")

mongo_spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("myApp") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.contacts") \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.1') \
        .getOrCreate()

#   .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.contacts") \

people = mongo_spark\
    .createDataFrame([("Bilbo Baggins",  "50"), ("Gandalf", "1000"), ("Thorin", "195"), ("Balin", "178"), ("Kili", "77"), ("Dwalin", "169"), ("Oin", "167"), ("Gloin", "158"), ("Fili", "82"), ("Bombur", "None")], ["name", "age"])

people.show()
people.printSchema()

people\
    .write\
    .format("mongo")\
    .mode("append")\
    .option("database", "test")\
    .option("collection", "contacts")\
    .save()


spark.stop()
mongo_spark.stop()
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>airbnb_python</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector -->
                <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

      </dependencies>
  </project>
```

trying to follow the documentation ( https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/#python-basics ), when running

> pyspark --conf
>   "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection?readPreference=primaryPreferred"
>   --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.myCollection"
>   --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1

on Windows console, with the code above I get the same error. On C:\Users\israel.ivy2\jars I have two jars: org.mongodb.spark_mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.3.0 and org.mongodb_mongo-java-driver-3.8.0.

I'm posting this question, because I ran out of ideas, I already consulted 4 data engineer with no luck, and I really need help, please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving dependency problems in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383460/resolving-dependency-problems-in-apache-spark)

Comment: You're mixing Scala 211 and 212